# How to show electron window on top of the screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, electron

I already have browser window which is running on background. I want to show that window on top of the screen When i call a function. But my initial window should be on background. if i use alwaysontop : true keeps my window always visible.

```js
// my initial window 
var electron = require('electron');
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:265,height:420,resizable:false,alwaysOnTop:false,frame:false})

ipcMain.on('showontop', function (event) {
 //it doesn't work
  mainWindow({alwaysOnTop:false});
})

function showwin()
{
ipcMain.on('showontop', function (event) {
 //it doesn't work
  mainWindow({alwaysOnTop:false});
})
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showwin();"> Click </button>
```

Comment: alwaysOnTop property value should be true.

Comment: I want to show my window on top when click event occurs, i simple make it by mainwin.setalwaysOnTop(true);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to show my window on top when click event occurs, simply make it by mainwin.setalwaysOnTop(true);

```js
// in electron 

mainwindow.setalwaysontop("true"); 
// once show then it leaves from top when click outside
settimeout(funtion()
{
  mainwindow.setalwaysontop("false");
},1000)
```

Comment: You could fix the typos: settimout => setTimeout; funtion => function; setalwaysontop  => setAlwaysOnTop; mainwindow => mainWindow